# Optimization for comparing every element of a list to every element in database using Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-1.10

I'm working on a project in **Django 1.10**, and one of my apps requires that I import a list of 500-100,000 IP addresses, then compare those 500-100,000 IP addresses to the ~25,000+ IP addresses stored in my **SQLite3** database. Unfortunately, this takes quite some time, which is something I greatly need to reduce.

My database comprises of a `Host` table with a field called `ipv4_address`.

Here's the relevant model.py:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    ipv4_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='ipv4', default='0.0.0.0', unique=True)
```

And here's the relevant views.py:

```
bad_ips = []
read_bad_ips = [ '500', 'to', '100000', 'ips', 'here', '...' ]

for ip in read_bad_ips:
    if Host.objects.filter(ipv4_address=ip).exists():
        bad_ips.append(Host.objects.get(ipv4_address=ip))
```

Where `read_bad_ips` is a list of IP addresses and `bad_ips` is a list of the IPs I want that exist in both the database *and* the `read_bad_ips` list.

**What would be the best way to optimize this snippet of code from views.py?**

Thanks!

**EDIT:** @nik_m's solution solved this crisis!

> `read_bad_ips = [ '500', 'to', '100000', 'ips', 'here', '...' ]`
>
> `addresses = Host.objects.values_list('ipv4_address', flat=True)`
>
> `bad_ips = list(set(read_bad_ips).intersection(addresses))`

Comment: Is read_bad_ips a list of distinct IPs, or does it contain duplicates? You could shave off some time by eliminating duplicates if they exist and don't care about ordering (read_bad_ips = list(set(read_bad_ips))

Comment: @Johnny, `read_bad_ips` only featured unique IP addresses. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
bad_ips = Host.objects.filter(ipv4_address__in=read_bad_ips).values_list('ipv4_address', flat=True)
```

which will get you a list (maybe emtpy, maybe not) of `ipv4_address` values that are in the `read_bad_ips` list.

[EDIT]:
Since you're using sqlite database and this db has its limitations (due to the large amount of values that you have) you can try this:

```
for addr in Host.objects.values_list('ipv4_address', flat=True).iterator():
    if addr in read_bad_ips:
        bad_ips.append(addr)
```

[EDIT 2]:
Try using `set`'s [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#set.intersection) method, like this:

```
read_bad_ips = [ '500', 'to', '100000', 'ips', 'here', '...' ]
addresses = Host.objects.values_list('ipv4_address', flat=True)

bad_ips = list(set(read_bad_ips).intersection(addresses))
```

Comment: This was one way I attempted it, but unfortunately it threw this error:

`Exception Type:  OperationalError`
`Exception Value:  too many SQL variables`

**Edit:** The reason it does this is because SQLite limits the max variable number to 999 to prevent excess memory allocation.

Comment: The length of the `read_bad_ips` list is about 500 elements? This is an sqlite3 issue. Are you planning on change your database? Because sqlite has its limitations...

Comment: We would like to stick with SQLite for this project. I'm holding out that someone has encountered an issue like this before, and has figured out some kind of workaround.

Comment: How about using an iterator to traverse your data? See my (updated) answer.

Comment: Just tried your updated answer. It works, but takes about 3 times longer than my original views.py, haha.

Thank you for assisting me with this, by the way.

Comment: How about now? Updated once more.

Comment: YES! That did the trick @nik_m !

**Thank you so so much!**

Loading time is practically instantaneous. :)

Comment: Very glad I could help! Very glad!